# parsing one-row json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

This is my simple json code:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "This message"
}
```

With firebug console, I can get the `status`:

```
$({"status":1,"message":"This message"}.status)[0];
>>> 1
```

But getting `message` at the same way won't work, I get `undefined`:

```
$({"status":1,"message":"This message"}.message)[0];
>>> undefined
```

I would obtain "This message". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var x= {"status":"1","message":"This message"};
    alert(x.message);
})​
```

look here http://jsfiddle.net/JxHme/

Answer (score 2):

Should it not be this syntax?

```
$({"status":1,"message":"This message"})[0].message
```

Answer (score 1):

try not using jquery...

```
var myjson = {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "This message"
};
document.writeln(myjson.status);
document.writeln(myjson.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery. POJS does the job

```
{"status":1,"message":"This message"}.message;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
alert({"status":1,"message":"This message"}.message)
```